# Error installing Meteor on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, curl, meteor

I'm having trouble installing Meteor on Ubuntu 14.04. I searched through previous answers, but none had the same problem that I'm having.

When I run the command given on the Meteor website:

```
sudo curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

I get the following message:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to meteorinstall-4168.kxcdn.com port 443: 拒绝连接
>   Retrying download in 5 seconds...

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
curl --insecure https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Comment: Thank you.I have tried.But it seems that it does't work.The err is the same.

Comment: check : `echo $(test -d /etc/pki/tls/certs)$?` is it `1` ?

Comment: If it is `1` try following steps:

Comment: `sudo mkdir -p /etc/pki/tls/certs`

Comment: `sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: Thanks.But it's not 1.It's 0.

Comment: Do you have some firewall or restriction issue ?

Comment: I'm a newer on ubuntu .The system is my new equipment.I didn't set any setting

Comment: Okay try this step by step:

Comment: `nano /etc/selinux/config`

Comment: locate this line `SELINUX=enforcing`

Comment: change this to `SELINUX=disabled` and restart you pc and try installing

Comment: Sorry.I can't find the file named "config".In my computer ,under the "selinux",there is only a "semanage.conf".

Comment: I tried.It didn't work.Can you give me a more convenient way to contact? Thanks

Comment: Do `cd` ,then do  `git clone git://github.com/meteor/meteor.git`

Comment: `cd meteor` and `./install.sh`

Comment: It's downloading .It may be useful.Thank you .Can you give me a more convenient way to contact?

Comment: Sorry.I have downloaded the git.But when I cd meteor and enter ./install.sh .It echoed no such file.

Comment: do `./meteor --help`

Comment: another err It's the first time you've run Meteor from a git checkout.
I will download a kit containing all of Meteor's dependencies.
#############################                                             40.7%
curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: 归档文件中异常的 EOF
tar: 归档文件中异常的 EOF
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Failed to install dependency kit.

Comment: Can you do this `./admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected through another pc? connecting directly my ubuntu laptop to my router worked for me

Answer (score 0):

We need first to know what this command does,

first it download a file, using this link https://install.meteor.com/. then execute it, that's it.

So read the sh file,

there is a link where it download a file. it's *

```
https://static-meteor.netdna-ssl.com/packages-bootstrap/${RELEASE}/meteor-bootstrap-${PLATFORM}.tar.gz
```

this link is related to your system. ${RELEASE} is the version you want to download and ${PLATFORM} is the system where u want to install into it,

it can be os.linux.x86_32 os.linux.x86_64.

Check your system and the file and download Meteor directly in the browser.

**This question may be so old but i still facing the same problem and i solved it this way.